# CSS perspective percentages and improper scaling

Tags: html, css, web, 3d, perspective

I'm trying to make a view of the inside of a room from a first person perspective using CSS and HTML. It's easy enough using the 3D transforms and the perspective attribute — the tutorials on the Internet explain it well, and I grasped it quite quickly.

However, for my purposes, I want the room to scale along with its parent container or the viewport, so it needs to be responsive. For this, I have started using percentages and ommiting the Z transform, which has gone quite well.

This works almost perfectly — the back, left, and right face stay in their place and retain their shape no matter the aspect ratio or size. However, the top and bottom faces seem to only properly display if the aspect ratio is square or portrait. Otherwise, the top and bottom faces are too short, and you can see the white background.

```css
:root {
    
}

body {
    margin: 0 !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}

div#main {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

/* Walls with perspective */

div#scene-3d {
    height: 100%;
    perspective: 600px;
    width: 100%;
}

div#room {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    width: 100%;
}

div.room-face {
/*  backface-visibility: hidden; */
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.room-face#face-back {
    background: #333;
    transform: rotateY(90deg) translateX(100%) rotateY(-90deg);
}

.room-face#face-left {
    background: #ddd;
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotateY(90deg) translateX(50%);
}

.room-face#face-right {
    background: #bbb;
    transform: translateX(50%) rotateY(-90deg) translateX(-50%);
}

.room-face#face-top {
    background: #666;
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotateX(-90deg) translateY(50%);
}

.room-face#face-bottom {
    background: #999;
    transform: translateY(50%) rotateX(90deg) translateY(-50%);
}


/***/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Merlin le Roi</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="scene-3d">
                <div id="room">
                    <div class="room-face" id="face-back">Back</div>
                    <div class="room-face" id="face-right">Right</div>
                    <div class="room-face" id="face-left">Left</div>
                    <div class="room-face" id="face-top">Top</div>
                    <div class="room-face" id="face-bottom">Bottom</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What am I missing here? Why do the side faces scale and adjust properly, while the top and bottom ones seem to short?

I tried fiddling around with the transforms to no avail. It seems the only fix for now is to set the height of the top and bottom face to something absurd, like 2000%, but it doesn't seem like a good fix.

Comment: I tried turning your code into a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/2518285), but it doesn't render as per your screen shots. Please edit your question to either include a stack snippet which demonstrates the problem, or at least include all the necessary code for someone else to assemble into a working example.

Comment: When I run your snippet, all I see is a simple black rectangle. Do you need to include the script from your `index.js` file? All the relevant code needs to be in the snippet ... a snippet can't reference files on your local machine.

Comment: @BrettDonald It seems to work on my machine, regardless of the script or not. I'll remove the unneeded code.

Comment: @BrettDonald Also, index.js was just some empty file, it doesn't matter here and it does nothing for the perspective view, all that is HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply `transform-origin' to the ceiling and floor (this can also be applied to walls), and you also need to give them the proper height. With your permission, I fixed your code a bit:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}

#main {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

/* Walls with perspective */

#scene-3d {
  height: 100%;
  perspective: 600px;
  width: 100%;
}

#room {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 100%;
}

.room-face {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  /* labels */
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-size: 136px;
  font-family: monospace;
  /* debugging */
  border: solid 10px red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#face-back {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateX(100%) rotateY(-90deg);
}

#face-left {
  background: #ddd;
  transform-origin: left;
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
}

#face-right {
  background: #bbb;
  transform-origin: right;
  transform: rotateY(-90deg);
  right: 0;
}

#face-top {
  background: blue;
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  transform-origin: top;
  height: 100vw;
}

#face-bottom {
  background: yellow;
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  transform-origin: bottom;
  height: 100vw;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="scene-3d">
    <div id="room">
      <div class="room-face" id="face-back">Back</div>
      <div class="room-face" id="face-right">Right</div>
      <div class="room-face" id="face-left">Left</div>
      <div class="room-face" id="face-top">Top</div>
      <div class="room-face" id="face-bottom">Bottom</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to (preferably without JS) scale these top and bottom elements so they are as responsive as left and right elements if you change the size of the parent? For some reason the left and right "walls" adjust to the size of the parent perfectly.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I updated my answer.

Comment: To each other! I was glad to help 